# Stuck on Boot Up Screen

Tags: raspberrypi

So I installed Ubuntu Core on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and after doing everything right, I turned on the Pi for the first time. It's stuck on this screen that shows the Ubuntu logo with text under it that says "Core". Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It could be that the Ubuntu-core image on the memory-card is corrupt; if you have another pi, you could try it on that one and see if it has the same response.  I would also remove & re-install the memory card and try.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu Core? Are you able to get to the GRUB menu at boot? Can you edit the kernel line and add "nomodeset" (behind "quiet splash") and see if that boots? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I am suffering of this right now, almost two years later.